# Drop legend using show.legend = FALSE does not work on a continuous aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to drop the legend by setting `show.legend = FALSE`. It works as expected when the `fill` variable is *discrete*:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, fill = factor(mpg))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]
However, when `fill` is mapped to a *continuous* variable, `show.legend = FALSE` does not drop the legend:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, fill = mpg)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Why doesn't `show.legend = FALSE` omit the legend for a continuous scale? How can I solve this?

I have `ggplot2 v.2.0.0` (author: Hadley Wickham)

Reference: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html

Comment: Does anyone think this is a bug?

Comment: `show.legend` works for a discrete scale though; `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill = factor(mpg))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE)`.  That it doesn't work for a continuous scale seems like a bug (or an undocumented feature...). Same in the recently released `ggplot2_2.1.0`.

Comment: I posted [an issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1568).

Comment: Thanks for the edit and feedback Henrik!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your example case, you can use `theme()`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill = mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting: if you add ``+ theme_bw()`` after ``theme(legend.position = 'none')``, the legend reappears. (I knew about ``legend.position`` but hadn't tested it on my MWE and my systematic use of ``theme_bw()`` at the end of my code reintroduced the legend). Edit: I should have known better.

Comment: that's because adding `theme_bw()` _afterwards_ cancels out the settings you apply in `theme()`. Add `+ theme_bw()` first and `+ theme(legend.position = 'none')` next, and you should be good

Comment: This actually also fix it when piping your ggplot to `plotly::ggplotly` ignores the `show.legend = FALSE` argument.